# PHP in_array returning wrong value

Tags: php, arrays

Here is the one value that can not determine PHP `in_array` function. I think this is issue with value but why ? I am stuck.

`"ZQjEa8EsL2kdHr2xD2jkoWj678FWsLL2Ng1tFjDV/Rgkt0CLiE4f+lvlYrdDjvq2"`

**PHP Example**

```
<?php
    $id = "ZQjEa8EsL2kdHr2xD2jkoWj678FWsLL2Ng1tFjDV/Rgkt0CLiE4f+lvlYrdDjvq2";
    $array['selected_options']['12251_12754_3'][0] = 0;

    var_dump(in_array($id, $array['selected_options']['12251_12754_3']));
?>
```

**Output**

```
true
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxr4go4CLSyUzRcFWQSkqMMs10cK12McoO8WjyKjCxSgrOz88y8zcwi282MfHyC/dsMQtyyVMPyg9u8TA2SfT1SRNO6csJ7IoxSWrrNBIyZpLJbGoKLEyWr04NSc1uSQ1JT6/oCQzP69YPTZa3dDIyNQw3tDI3NQk3hgoYBALtNTAmourLLEoPqU0t0AjMy8erF8D6CAdBRLM0tS0/v8fAA)

> Question : Anybody knows why this happen or what I do instead ?

Answers much appriciated !

Comment: that's what happens when you compare in `in_array` loosely

Comment: heck you can even do `var_dump(in_array(null, $array['selected_options']['12251_12754_3']));` and it'll still yield `true`

Comment: You are searching a string variable in int array declare array as string or id as int try again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Searches for needle in haystack using loose comparison unless strict is set.

Append the third argument with **true** to get the result you need.

```
var_dump(in_array($id, $array['selected_options']['12251_12754_3'], true));
```

See [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php).

Comment: Isn't that gonna always throw false ?